# How to stop camera from zooming beyond the map?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zooming

My current camera movement script works to zoom and bound to the map when panning. In my game, the player will be able to zoom and when you zoom out you can see the void beyond the map and when you zoom in the camera no longer goes to the edge of the map. What would I need to do to make sure "zoom out" stays within the bounds of the map and "zoom in" continues to go to the edge?

It is a 2d game. The map width is 1920, height is 1080. The map is an image with a sprite renderer component attached. To be clear, an example of a game with similar function that I want is the game "GardenScapes". The player will be able to zoom and pan around the scene in that way. Part of my town gets cut off if I zoom in and try to pan to the edge or if I zoom out and pan to the edge the void shows beyond the map. It is not as easy as just restricting where you can pan over because the zoom still causes the above problems.

Current Script:

```
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            touchStart = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            multiTouch = false;

        }

        if(Input.touchCount == 2)
        {
            multiTouch = true;

            Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

            Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
            Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

            float prevMagnitude = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
            float currentMagnitude = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;

            float difference = currentMagnitude - prevMagnitude;

            zoom(difference * zoomPinchSpeed);
        }
        else if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) && multiTouch == false)
        {
            Vector3 direction = touchStart - cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            cam.transform.position += direction;

            targetPosition = cam.transform.position;

            targetPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(targetPosition.x, minPosition.x, maxPosition.x);
            targetPosition.y = Mathf.Clamp(targetPosition.y, minPosition.y, maxPosition.y);
            targetPosition.z = -0.01f;

            cam.transform.position = targetPosition;
        }
        zoom(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * zoomMouseSpeed);
    }

    void zoom(float increment)
    {
        cam.orthographicSize = Mathf.Clamp(cam.orthographicSize - increment, zoomOutMin, zoomOutMax);
    }
```

Comment: I assume you would need to calculate where the edges of your map are ensure that the camera is moved accordingly / can not zoom further out beyond a certain point ... there is too little information for us to properly answer here: Is the camera rotated or purely top down? Is the map rotated on Y axis / camera rotated on its local Z axis or always a fixed and aligned rotation? Is the size of the map known etc ...

Comment: I think one approach you could go would be using world point on the edge of the map, `ScreenToWorldPoint` from the edge of the screen .. if the edge of the screen lies beyond the map edge move your camera about the delta in the other direction. If you do this for all four map and screen edges you should be fine ... edge case will of course be e.g. you can zoom out too much -> adjust your settings to prevent that case ;)

Comment: oh it would be also important to know: `The "map" is an image/sprite.` ... which of those? Because `Image` I would assume to be already in a screenspace Canvas anyway .. while a `SpriteRenderer` would rather be in 3D world space .. and seems to be rather the case if you zoom the camera  - if it was in the UI you could as well zoom the UI instead

Comment: I updated my post with the info requested. It is a 2d game. The map width is 1920, height is 1080. The map is an image with a sprite renderer component attached. To be clear, an example of a game with similar function that I want is the game "GardenScapes". The player will be able to zoom and pan around the scene in that way.